# jQuery does not output the same design for the element

Tags: jquery, html

I have a form for pharmacy sales. Because a customer usually buy more then medicine at a time, many fields should be repeated for every medicine the customer buys, like: category, medicine name, amount and price. To have this functionality I have put a button at the end of the form (inside the form) and used jQuery to create the extra fields mentioned above.

Now, Because I have used a website template, when the extra fields are created by clicking on the respective button, the select tags do not take their pre-defined design, but all the other tags do.

This is the JQuery Code that appends the fields before the button in the form:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#more').click(function(){
    $('#more').before('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Amount</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true"></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Price per pack</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true"></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Total Price</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true"></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Whole Sale Price</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="This is the actual price to be purchased accordingly" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true" value="40" readonly></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Retail Price</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true"></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required"><label class="">Medicine Name</label><select class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Country" data-init-plugin="select2"><option value="AK">Aspirin</option><option value="HI">Necotin</option><option value="CA">Violin</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="WA">Washington</option></select></div></div></div><hr>');
  });

});
```

And this part of the form that the fields are to be added:

```
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                <label>Whole Sale Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="email" placeholder="This is the actual price to be purchased accordingly" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true" value="40" readonly>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-12">
              <div class="form-group form-group-default">
                <label>Retail Price</label>
                <input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <hr>

            <!-- Fields are added here -->

          <button class="btn btn-success btn-cons m-t-10" id="more"><span class="pg pg-printer"> </span> &nbsp More</button>
```

Can anyone tell me what is the problem with that select input field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because in the template they are library. and you must recall this library when you add new Html. i assume that they use select2 library so you need to call select2() function after adding the Html :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#more').click(function(){
    $('#more').before('<div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Amount</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true"></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Price per pack</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true"></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Total Price</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true"></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Whole Sale Price</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="This is the actual price to be purchased accordingly" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true" value="40" readonly></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default"><label>Retail Price</label><input type="number" name="email" placeholder="Write how many packs is purchased" class="form-control" required="" aria-required="true"></div></div></div><div class="row"><div class="col-sm-12"><div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required"><label class="">Medicine Name</label><select class="full-width" data-placeholder="Select Country" data-init-plugin="select2"><option value="AK">Aspirin</option><option value="HI">Necotin</option><option value="CA">Violin</option><option value="NV">Nevada</option><option value="OR">Oregon</option><option value="WA">Washington</option></select></div></div></div><hr>');

    $('[data-init-plugin="select2"]').select2();
  });
});
```

Comment: Dear Mustapha, It was all what I needed. Thank you